# MonetDB insert bulk data best practice

Tags: .net, odbc, monetdb

What is the best practice for inserting data via `INSERT` statements?

In MonetDB exists operation for bulk data loading (`COPY INTO`) but it requires file or stream and this solution doesn't suit my project.

I tried to use `START TRANSACTION; ... COMMIT`; but my best result was 220 000 records in 1 minute.

I use MonetDB in my .net project via ODBC connection.

How can I insert data via `INSERT` the fastest way?

Answer (score 0):

You could try multiple (say, 1000) values per INSERT:

```
START TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE foo (a INTEGER, b STRING);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c');
COMMIT;
```

But really, bulk load with `COPY INTO` is generally a much better idea...

Answer (score -1):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MonetDb.Mapi

```
int count;
string tableName; // "\"MyTable\""
string columns; // '"' + string.Join("\", \"", columnArray) + '"'

dbCommand.Execute($"COPY {count} RECORDS INTO {tableName} FROM STDIN ({columns}) DELIMITERS ',','\\n','\\'';");

string records; // string.Join('\n', recArrayOfArray.Select(x => string.Join("," x))
dbCommand.Execute(records);
```